# How can I make a button object that has a parameter which can change iconData dynamically in flutter?

Tags: flutter, object, oop, dart, flutter-layout

I am practicing flutter and building a simple app with buttons, each buttons contains different values and those values are stored inside the object's parameter. Now, I want to create a button object where I can change its button icon dynamically.

I want it to look like this:

```
    Expanded(child: NavButton(buttonIcon: home,callFunction: buttonClick,buttonName: 'Home'),) ,
```

I tried declaring a field name buttonIcon inside my object's class but it goes like this:

```
  class NavButton extends StatelessWidget{
  
  final IconData buttonIcon;
  
  final String buttonName;

  final Function callFunction;

  const NavButton({
   required this.buttonIcon,
   required this.buttonName,
   required this.callFunction
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      child: FlatButton(
      //this will make an error stating that the getter for 'buttonIcon' isn't defined for the type 'Icons'
      child:Icon(Icons.buttonIcon, size: 45,),
      onPressed: (){
        callFunction(buttonName);          
        }
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

What can I do to make it recognize my 'buttonIcon' field? and if there's an easy way for this? thanks in advance. :)

Comment: buttonIcon is a property from your NavButton class not from the Icons class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a syntax error. Try the following, simply passing your IconData as the posititional argument to your Icon:

```
  child:Icon(buttonIcon, size: 45,),
```

Comment: it actually work, thanks for the help. :)